# R: group by a data set, with condition that all values in a particular column in the group match some requirement

Tags: r, group-by

Got a data set like:

```
A B
a x
a y
b z
b z
c x
c z
```

Now I would like to group by A, with values in B in each group contains 'x' or 'y' only. e.g only 'c' would be chosen.

Any simple function for this solution? Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can select groups where `all` the values are either `"x"` or `"y"`.

In base R, we can use `ave` with `subset`

```
unique(subset(df, ave(B %in% c('x', 'y'), A, FUN =  all), select = A))

#  A
#1 a
#8 d
```

Or with `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(A) %>%
  filter(all(B %in% c('x', 'y'))) %>%
  distinct(A)
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(A = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd'), 
                 B = c('x', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'z', 'x', 'z', 'x', 'x'))
```

Comment: many thanks! I got the right answer from option2, still dno't know why option1 results at 0 row